# How atomic is Compare and Swap against global variable in modern computer?

Tags: c++, multithreading, hardware, compare-and-swap

Assume we implement in a modern programming language like C++. Let's say we have 5 threads t1 to t5, and we also have an array of timestamps TS[5] one for each thread. We also have a global timestamp GT which will increase gradually as the process runs. So now each of the five thread tx makes a local copy of TS[x] as local_ts and is trying to do a compare and swap on its timestamp CAS(&TS[x],local_ts,TS). Then my question is will the final timestamps in TS[5] reflect the order of when each thread's compare and swap actually takes place. For example, if a thread does CAS before another thread, its stored timestamp must be less than or equal to the other thread's timestamp.
Please refer to the following as a simple code example in C++

```
TS timestamps[5];//assuming TS ia a class enclosing a long value.
TS GT=0;//it is periodically increased by another thread not shown here.

void work_load(int id){
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++);//simulate the thread does some work
    TS local = timestamps[id];
    timestamps[id].compare_exchange_strong(local,GT,std::some_memotry_order);
//each thread reads other threads' entries in the array and does things accordingly to their values against its own value
}

void main(){
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
       std::thread t(work_load,i); 
    }
}
```

So the goal is to design a transactional system with no locks. Each transaction appends its updates to a record as deltas. In validation phase, a transaction needs to check its deltas against other deltas on the same records that may conflict. I'm trying to design a global data structure which records atomically when each transaction starts its commit phase so transactions can decide if they need to abort based on observing who makes the conflicting deltas.

Comment: Scenario: fetchTime(); thread swapped out by OS for a time; CAS time stamp. So swapped in timestamp could be older at time of swap. So not necessarily even with a monotonic clock consistent across threads. This involves more than CAS atomicity

Comment: It's as atomic as you make it.  For example, that's what the `memory_order` parameters are for in `std::atomic`'s [`comapre_exchange_*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) functions.

Comment: I'm confused. You mention `GT`, but don't actually use it anywhere - how does it fit into the picture? What is this `CAS` function that takes `TS` as the third parameter; how, if at all, is it related to say `std::atomic<T>::compare_exchange_strong`? If thread `x` is the only one that touches `TS[x]`, why do you need atomic operations in the first place? What concurrent access are they meant to protect against?

Comment: What do you mean by "the order of when each thread's compare and swap actually takes place"? There's no global order of operations across multiple atomic objects; there's a separate order of operations on each atomic object. The timelines for different objects must be consistent with *happens-before* relationship, but I see nothing in your description that would establish such a relationship between operations on `T[i]` and `T[j]` for `i != j`

Comment: Hello, sorry for making it a bit confusing. So there is a global variable GT that is gradually increasing. Each thread will try to modify a variable assigned to it with the current GT value using compare and swap. So my naive belief was if a thread CAS a GT larger than the other thread, its CAS must happen after that one. Is this guaranteed in modern hardware? Thanks.

Comment: So even the seemingly atomic CAS still does not guarantee the fetch of the global variable and actually writing it will be atomic? Thanks I feel that's what I'm asking. I will also look into memory order and those std::atomic's.

Comment: My plan is to design lock-free data structures using CAS or other similar operations. So I consider the CAS as an atomic operation to change the state of a thread which will be observed by other threads and they later can make decisions on top of that. I omit the observing part to make the question more specific about atomic operations.

Comment: Variables don't increase themself. So something else is modifying GT. And GT is not T[i]. You have 2 operations, not one. Stuff can happen between them unless you lock all possibilities of that out. Even if each operation is atomic, you have a race. Read-modify-write is not Read one thing-modify-write something else.

Comment: Hello yes I agree. I'd expect a race. I would expect a thread periodically does atomic add on the GT. I also understand the read modify write thing, but I'm wondering if the fetching of the global variable GT is included as part of the CAS? Thanks.

Comment: No, fetching `GT` is not part of the CAS. `std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&TS[x], local_ts, GT)` is equivalent to `auto local_gt = GT.load(); std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&TS[x], local_ts, local_gt)`. There is no magical simultaneous super-atomic double-CAS on two unrelated atomics. It is pointless to use CAS with `T[x]`, or even to make it atomic in the first place, as there's no race on it - it's only ever accessed by a single thread.

Comment: Anyway, what's the ultimate goal of the exercise? What did you plan to do with the answer to your question? What do you believe depends on it? As I said, the very question of "when each thread's compare and swap actually takes place" doesn't make sense - in a parallel program, there's no single timeline on which events "take place" in some global order, so you can't generally say that one operation "took place" before or after the other. There's no single uniform forward-moving clock by which to measure the concept of "when".

Comment: Hello, I see and thank you. My goal was to create a lock-free transactional system where each transaction can use CAS to update its state to a global timestamp to reflect the time the CAS actually takes place. My goal is to let other transactions see each other's timestamp to determine who did the CAS earlier.

Comment: You don't need a _time_ stamp for that. You just need a global sequence number. For each transaction, do `fetch_add(1)` on an `atomic<long>` counter to get the sequence number, and then if any conflicting transactions are found, declare the one with the lowest sequence number to be the winner. It shouldn't matter that you can't know which one _actually_ "happened first." What matters is, you have a means that everybody can agree on to decide which transaction is the keeper, and which other(s) need to be rolled-back.

Comment: Hello Soloman, thank you for the suggestion. But I was hoping to use it for the validation phase of my transactional system. I'm wondering will TS[x]=fetch_add(GT) will be completely atomic then? Thanks.

Comment: Or more specifically and unfortunately, atomic<long> ts.store(fetch_add(1)) is not atomic itself but two separate operations. Seem like I will have a hard time finding a solution to make this atomic.

Comment: I don't understand why you talk about `TS[x]`. You seem to say above that `TS[x]` is only ever accessed by thread _x._ If that's true, then it's simply not part of the picture. The only question is whether or not `counter.fetch_add(1)` is guaranteed to return a unique value from every call. And, yes. Enforcing that guarantee is the whole point of `fetch_add`.

Comment: On the other hand: If there _is_ some other thread besides thread _x_ that accesses `TS[x]`, then you will need to use some means (e.g., a `std::mutex`) to ensure that both threads agree upon what value it holds and when. [P.S., I am voting to close this question unless you can add a code example. Talking about code is much more worth while when everybody can _see_ the code that they are talking about.]

Comment: Thank you I see and I agree on that. My goal is trying to not use a lock or mutex on this and that's why I was asking because I omit the part of concurrent reads on the TS[x] for each thread. I can try to modify with some simple code and then make it more worth to talk about. Thanks.

Comment: OK, You added some code, but it doesn't say much. It shows five threads that do not interact with each other at all. Each thread _i_ reads the _uninitialized_ value of it's own, private `TS[i]`, and then if the value is not changed (which, of course it isn't because no other thread touches `TS[i]`), it assigns a new value. End of story. You ask "how atomic is it?" But what does that even mean when all you do is store a value into a variable that nobody ever looks at again?

Comment: Hello, yes in my code I did not show interaction because I don't want to get too much into the details of their interaction. I assumed after CAS they will need to read other threads' values stored in the array. This design is more of a design blueprint other than an actual implementation yet. I will modify the code a bit.

Comment: Please use `@username` to reply, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: Re, "...reads other threads' entries in the array and does things accordingly." That's what somebody would need to see in order to say whether it makes any sense. Suppose thread i is comparing its own `timestamp[i]` to `timestamp[j]`. Does it matter whether it happens before or after any particular iteration of thread j has assigned `timestamp[j]`? If it matters, how will you ensure that the comparison happens at the "right" time? Or, what if `compare_exchange_strong` returns `false`? You haven't showed code that handles that case. Can't say if the code I haven't seen makes any sense or not.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks I see your point. I will update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So many thanks and kudos to the people in the comment section. So my question is answered. The atomic CAS does not include an atomic read of the value I want to replace with upon success. Basically CAS(&object, expected, new_value) does not include fetching new_value from the global variable as an operation within the atomic CAS. Read_modify_write only guarantees the atomicity on the target object.